# Как правильно написать слово (с,сс)у(ж,жж)е(н,нн)ый?

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5):

Если жених, то суженый. А если его сузили, то он будет уже суженный:) Если же от глагола "ссудить", то будет ссуженный.

Comment: интересно, а от чего там может быть удвоенное Ж? От хитрости автора?

Comment: Ого!Это задание ведь было на олимпиаде для учеников 11 класса!